# Condition if request named parameter has this value in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I was trying to make a condition that will have particular SQL query condition if request named parameter's value is inactive.

```
if (isset($this->request->named['status:inactive'])) {
  $conditions["ApplicationCode.status"] = 'inactive';
}
```

Pagination part, that will access the `condition` variable btw:

```
       $this->paginate = array(
            'order' => array('ApplicationCode.code' => 'ASC'),
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'limit' => 50,
            'contain' => array(
                'Role',
                'Application' => array(
                    'conditions' => array('Application.state != ' => Application::ARCHIVED),
                    'User'
                )
            )
        );
```

I'm quite new to PHP too and I'm using CakePHP framework.

The above code didn't work. If I remove the `:inactive`, it's working. But I would like to use that condition if the status parameter is equals to inactive.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($this->request->named['status'])) {
  $conditions["ApplicationCode.status"] = $this->request->named['status];
}
```

or

```
if (isset($this->request->named['status']) && $this->request->named['status'] == 'inactive') {
  $conditions["ApplicationCode.status"] = 'inactive';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for two versions. I'm learning a lot now. I'll accept the answer til SO allows me.

Comment: And don't use named params, use query strings - see [passed-named-or-query-string-params](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/05/04/passed-named-or-query-string-params/).